# 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error:

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

The following is my code so far:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
    url(r'^register_view/$', views.register_view, name='register_view'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name="logout_view"),
    url(r'^profile_view/$', views.profile_view, name="profile_view"),
    url(r'password_change/$',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html',success_url='/accounts/password_change_done')),
    url(r'password_change_done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html')),
    url(r'password_reset/$',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.txt',success_url='/accounts/password_reset_done/',from_email='mpho.maleka3@gmail.com')),
    url(r'password_reset_done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html')),
    url(r'password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',success_url='/accounts/password_reset_confirm/'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'password_reset_complete/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html')),
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `'registration/password_reset_form.html'` file?

Comment: Django will show you in which exact template and which line is causing the error. All you need to do is edit that line from `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}` to  `{% url 'accounts:password_reset_confirm' %}`

Comment: {% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-10  mx-auto'>
        <h1>Set your Password</h1>
        <form method='post' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <span style='margin-bottom: 12px;'></span>
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-block btn-info'>Set new password</button>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

Comment: Other urls such as `password_change` work well?

Comment: Something seems missing in the `action=...`.

Comment: for success_url you have to use reverse_lazy

Answer (score 6):

You need to know that django uses the default template for the email message subject  which is (password_reset_email.html) under the name `password_reset_confirm`, but your are using a namespace, acocunts:`password_reset_confirm`, all what you need to do is

1. Override the template path  using this attr `email_template_name`

```
auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
  template_name ='accounts/registration/password_reset.html',
  email_template_name = 'accounts/registration/password_reset_email.html'),
```

2. Set up your email configurations in **settings.py** to send your email, without getting a error (Errno 111) connection refused

Answer (score 5):

To get Django to use your app's `registration/password_reset_form.html'` template, you need to move that app *above* `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Note that Django doesn't make it easy to use a namespace with the password reset views. Once you have fixed this `NoReverseMatch`, you may find you have to fix similar errors. It would probably be easier to move your password reset URL patterns into a `urls.py` that does not have a namespace.

Comment: That's the best solution. So e.g. move it to your project's urls.py, where you normally just reference your app's urls.py

Comment: Just a clarification, only the `password_reset_confirm` view needs to be moved to the root urls.py for the email template to be able to "reverse URL it".

Comment: @netcyrax yes, but if you only move the `password_reset_confirm` pattern, then you might get a `NoReverseMatch` later for `password_reset_done` or `password_reset_complete`. I wouldn’t recommend moving one pattern but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing it like this

***reset_password

reset_password_done

reset_password_confirm

reset_password_complete***

You need to write it this way

***reset_password

password_reset_done 

password_reset_confirm 

password_reset_complete***

it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).