# Django password_reset with appname

Tags: python, django

I'm using auth views for for resetting password in django. Since I've declared this views inside my users app and used appname for the URLs I'm getting an error. I know that I should change the URL inside the django pre-built templates but I don't know the best way of overriding this kind of stuff.

---

this is URL.py of my user application:

```
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),]
```

this is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /users/password-reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

this is the line it's referring:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782462/password-reset-confirm-not-found-password-reset-confirm-is-not-a-valid-view  does it help ?

Comment: first part is not helping but probably the second will fix it, however, I wanted to avoid that solution and fix it in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need add the module name to access it, like this:

```
{% url 'users:password_reset_confirm' %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: this is probably the solution but I think the way to change it is to change the files from base files of django and I don't know if it is recommended or not

Comment: I believe that has`t a fixed recommended way. So, Is hard to attach new urls on the django defaults modules, and maybe is unnecessary in this cases. I see two great ways:

- You can add this views it on the main urls.py, and you won't need reference any module. 

- If you have created a custom user, make this views together, I always see peoples using this way.

Answer (score 0):

It took my whole day to figure it out: I did everything to figure this out but finally found the answer

Don't write the password reset, password reset done, password reset confirm and password reset complete in the same app_name url_pattern

The correct way to write those in the root projectname url_pattern

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).